# Xamarin incrementing loop of chat bubble feature

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm creating a chatbot app with Xamarin.Forms, when I send a message and the chatbot replies the chat bubbles kinda do this incrementing looping stack thing. The first reply has one response, the second one has two, the third one has three and so on.
[image]

I've been using a sorta obscure bot framework called Oscova Bot and after checking for an answer on their forums I think it has something to do with an event handler and it occuring more than once or something.
Heres the C# code.

```
 /// <summary>
    /// View model for the ChatbotPage.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public class ChatbotPageViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// A field for TextToSend
        /// </summary>
        private string _texttosend;

        /// <summary>
        /// An Instance of a new SIML Oscova Chatbot
        /// </summary>
        public OscovaBot chatbot;

        /// <summary>
        /// A collection/list of chat message items
        /// </summary>
        public ObservableCollection<ChatMessageModel> Messages { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<ChatMessageModel>();

        /// <summary>
        /// The text that the user inputs
        /// </summary>
        public string TextToSend
        {
            get
            {
                return _texttosend;
            }

            set
            {
                if (_texttosend != value)
                {
                    _texttosend = value;

                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// A command for sending the users messages
        /// </summary>
        public ICommand SendCommand { get; set; }


        /// <summary>
        /// ChatPageViewModel Constructor
        /// </summary>
        public ChatbotPageViewModel()
        {
            SendCommand = new RelayCommand(Send);

            chatbot = new OscovaBot();
            var assembly = IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(typeof(MainPage)).Assembly;
            Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("BluePillApp.Helpers.nice.siml");

            chatbot.Import(XDocument.Load(stream));
            chatbot.Trainer.StartTraining();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This function sends a message
        /// </summary>
        public void Send()
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextToSend))
            {
                //This adds a new message to the messages collection
                Messages.Add(new ChatMessageModel() { Text = TextToSend, User = App.User });

                //This gets the chatbots response for each message
                chatbot.MainUser.ResponseReceived += async (sender, args) =>
                {
                    await Task.Delay(1500);
                    Messages.Add(new ChatMessageModel() { Text = args.Response.Text });
                };

                var result = chatbot.Evaluate(TextToSend);
                result.Invoke();

                //Removes the text in the Entry after message is sent
                TextToSend = string.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could add the break point to the line `Messages.Add(new ChatMessageModel() { Text = args.Response.Text });` and check if it been called multi times .

Comment: Yes, I just tried that and it looks like the text/reply from the chatbot is always added more than once. Whats causing this and how could I fix it?

Comment: You could share a sample so that I could test it on my side .

Comment: This is prolly because you are adding multiple event handlers in the `Send` method. A similiar post has already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60244868/event-handler-incrementing-loop-issue